# How to define a function which takes a number as parameter and returns it's square, in angular?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, function

I have an array of numbers, and I need to display these numbers and their respective squares along with it. For this I need to define a function which take number as an parameter and returns its square as a value.I have tried defining a function as

```
 Numbers:number[]=[2,3,5,7];
  square(cm:number):number{
  return cm*cm;
 }
```

Comment: So what's the issue in this?

Comment: Looks like it should work, what problems are you encountering? `square(3)` -> `9`?

Comment: Please show the code how you are using

Comment: You have declared the method. But where are you calling?

Comment: i am calling it in .html by below given way please go through it and let me know the mistake

Comment: Please look at my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use  `{{square(c1)}}` so that you call the method and get the squared value

```
<h4> List Of Numbers</h4>
  <div class="row"*ngFor="let c1 of Numbers;index as i">
   <div class="col-1   m-1"> 
    {{i}}   
  </div>
  <div class="col-2 border bg-light m-1"> 
   {{c1}}
  </div>
   <div class="col-2 border bg-light m-1">
     {{square(c1)}}
  </div>
  <div class="col-1 border fa fa-trash m-1 bg-white" (click)="remove(c1)">
  </div>
```

Comment: i tried this before also and i tried it once again..it isn't working. showing ";" expected

Comment: @amansolanki, can you please post your code on stackblitz. According to me, it should work

Answer (score 0):

You can use map function

```
var number = [2, 3, 5, 7]; 
var square = number.map(c=> c*c);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using it wrong way .Call your function in the html.

```
<h4> List Of Numbers</h4>
  <div class="row" *ngFor="let c1 of Numbers;index as i">
   <div class="col-1   m-1">
    {{i}}
</div>
<div class="col-2 border bg-light m-1">
    {{c1}}
</div>
<div class="col-2 border bg-light m-1">
    {{square(c1)}}
</div>
<div class="col-1 border fa fa-trash m-1 bg-white" (click)="remove(c1)">
</div>
```

Comment: its woking very fine. I think you updated your comment that how can you call a function from html. You can very well call a function from html because anything written inside {{}} is evaluated in angular.

Answer (score 0):

```
import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'square',
})
export class SquarePipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: any, ...args: any[]): any {

    return value * value
  }

}
```

html:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of iterms">{{ item | square}}</ng-container>
```

module.ts:

```
declarations:[SquarePipe ]
```

Comment: cant use it as i am going through my course and i pipe topic haven't been taught yet ;)

Comment: <ng-container *ngFor="let item of iterms">{{ item * item}}</ng-container>